# What is build.xml in android

Tags: android, build.xml

I'm new to android i have very much confusion about what exactly build.xml. I have read various answers anyone please tell me what exactly build.xml in android.

Comment: Read https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_use_of_the_build.xml_file%3F

Answer (score 1):

Apache ANT is tool to automate build of java projects ,by providing instructions in build.xml file ,eclipse uses ant to build projects .I suggest Android Studio as IDE which uses Gradle for build of android project and that is officially supported by google.